# Passing a variable between TFS 2018 Release Task and then use that variable in a gate step

Tags: variables, azure-devops

I'm trying to use a variable that I have defined in a release Task and then pull that value into a Gate step. It's just a simple pipeline to demonstrate some integration with ServiceNow.
[image]

After a Build, a release is kicked off. The code is automatically copied to the "test" environment.
The Next step is a Power-Shell script that will create a Change Request in ServiceNow. I am able to create the CR and then parse the json that is returned to capture the Change Request Number. I use the following command to save the CR Number in the last line of the Power-Shell:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=crnumber]$crnumber
```

In the next step I use an extension to save the variables out to a JSON file.
Then for debugging I have a Power-Shell step that reads the CR variable.
It produces this output in the logs

```
2020-01-16T19:08:05.4137159Z Read variable after
2020-01-16T19:08:05.4138360Z --------------------1--------------------------
2020-01-16T19:08:05.4140620Z CHG0417736
2020-01-16T19:08:05.4141674Z --------------------2-------------------------
2020-01-16T19:08:05.4143096Z CHG0417736
2020-01-16T19:08:05.4144492Z --------------------3-------------------------
2020-01-16T19:08:05.5656992Z ##[section]Finishing: Read CR fron ENV
```

After that I set up Post Deployment conditions. 1 approval (me), and then another Extension that will query ServiceNow for the "Ready to Implement" State.

Note if I enter the CR Number (CHG0417736) is does work as expected. But I would like to use the $crnumber variable.

What am I missing here? Unfortunately I can't just add the Power-Shell Task here to try and debug the variable
[image]

Comment: I think that `Post-deployment conditions` can't recognize your agent's environment variable. And it's by design, check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#access-variables-through-the-environment):  *Notice that variables are also made available to scripts through environment variables.* So I think gates can't access your environment var and can't analyse the value of the `$(crnumber)`. That could be cause of your issue.

Comment: A quick and dirty workaround could be the following setting: 1.) create Global Variablegroup in the Library with your variable `crnumber` and initalize it with `0` - 2.) insteat of Write-Host `"##vso[task.setvariable variable=crnumber]$crnumber` use the REST API [Variablegroups Update](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) and a valid PAT to update your Varaible with your value - 3.) link the Variablegroup to your pipeline, `$(crnumber)` should now work. I don't test the whole workflow but it should works.

Comment: Can Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue"  be used to set the env:$VARIABLE_NAME?

Comment: @PatDelaney I can't find same gate like yours, does it come from one extension?

Comment: Here is the URL: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=colinsalmcorner.colinsalmcorner-snow-extensions

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm trying to reproduce same issue to find workaround but I'm stuck at creating third-party service now connection...  I checked the pic from [this page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=colinsalmcorner.colinsalmcorner-snow-extensions&ssr=false#overview) and I think this gate only accepts pipeline variables instead of environment variables. Please try defining one pipeline variable(crnumber) with one number for your release pipeline, agree with **Mar Tin**, that should work!

Comment: I am able to finally pass a value, unfortunately it's not the correct one. The Gate process appears to be reading the variable at the start of the release process. I have a task that updated that value, but the gate is not reading it. It's not specific to the ServiceNow gate, because I added a Rest API step to test the variable and it's using the previous value.

Comment: I do have an open Support request in with Microsoft, I will update when they help me fix the issue.

Comment: Hi friend, is there any update for this issue? What's the result of support request? If you need any further assistance, feel free to contact us :)

Comment: I have a call with Microsoft support today. I will update after the call.